# How to run functions that take a not-one quantitiy of arguments with varagrs as parameters?

Tags: python, variadic-functions

I want to create a utility function that lets me schedule some arbitrary coroutine that can take some arbitrary number of arguments like this:

```
import asyncio

async def schedule(coro, *args, time_in_seconds=10):
    await asyncio.sleep(time_in_seconds)
    return await coro(args)
```

Doing some experiments in the python console gave me an error when I tried that on a function that takes two arguments. My guess is that `*args` is turned into a list of values, which is treated as one singular parameter in the function call.

So my question is if it's possible to call a function with `*args` as a parameter and have python treat the elements of the function as the parameters instead of the list `*args`

Comment: `coro(*args)`…‽

Comment: Oh, I literally didn't know this was possible... thanks!